# Need to select and delete features in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute

I'm new to ModelBuilder and I'm planning to take some class of it, but in the meantime I have a project with a relative easy task.

The high-level plan of this project is:

- Load shapefile into modelbuilder [USER PARAMETER]
- Select by attribute and delete selected features
- Load another shapefile into modelbuilder [USER PARAMETER]
- Make a buffer of 15 meters of this recently loaded shapefile
- ERASE first shapefile with the second shapefile (buffered)
- Add Field to the output of the ERASE process.
- Use Field Calculator to calculate meters on this new field(!shape.length@meters!)
- Select all features that are <200 meters and delete them
- Make a Centroid of the result that is >200 meters.

My problem is that I can't select and delete features after the Field Calculator step.

Does someone have an idea of what I did wrong?

A snapshot of what I have so far:

[image: Modelbuilder task]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you don't need to delete the feature in your case. Just make sure that you use a SQL statement together with your "Make FEature Layer" in order to only select the feature that you want to use for processing. You can also use "[select layer by attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000)" with the "switch" selection if you have a selection.

If you really want to delete, you can use "[delete Feature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000036000000)" as a tool. Again, you'll need a "make feature layer" and a "select layer by attribute" first.

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.4, the features get deleted from the table. But the map is still showing them. Here is my script:
`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("GDV.test", "DELETE_LAYER", "LZ > 8")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("DELETE_LAYER")`

Comment: have you tried to refresh your map ?